# Can we define surface integral on 'bad surface'?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, curves-and-surfaces

We can define a surface integral on a piecewise smooth surface, but if the surface is not piecewise smooth can we use measure theory to generalize the definition of surface integral? And does Stokes formula still holds?

Comment: Look into the book H. Federer: Geometric Measure Theory (1969) . There you will find answers to questions of this sort.

Comment: For a piecewise smooth differential form, just apply Stokes on each piece, Effectively you treat the surface as if the different pieces were pulled apart. But if the boundary contributions are given by continuous forms, agreeing across boundaries that get joined together, the integrals cancel.